# Remove status bar from a AVPlayerViewController and MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 10

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an app configured via `Info.plist` for hiding the status bar, but it is remaining as part of the video controls. Is it possible to remove the status bar that is shown as part of the controls of the `AVPlayerViewController` or `MPMoviePlayerController` classes?

I've tested in iOS 9 and 10 devices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below options to hide status bar

hide statusBar using bellow line...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

otherwise use this bellow line..

```
mpviewController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

OR

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```